# Reading a file line by line in c# and inserting into access database?

Tags: c#, oledb, readline

I am writing a simple c# application wherein I read from a file a line, split it, and insert the corresponding tokens into an access database after suitable conversion. I am using a stream reader to read the input file line by line. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
using(reader = Streamreader(filepath)
{
    while((line = reader.readline()) != null)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.split('\t');
        mycommand.commandtext = "INSERT INTO table_name (name, property) VALUES (@xname, @xproperty)";
        mycommand.parameters.addwithvalue("@xname", tokens[0]);
        mycommand.parameters.addwithvalue("@xproperty", float.parse(tokens[1]);
        mycommand.executenonquery();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the input file contains 6 distinct lines, then only the values associated with the first line are duplicated 6 times into my database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it `command` or `mycommand`? You've used both in your sample code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! fixed it!

Comment: is the reader stepping through all the lines i.e. does the line ((line = reader.readline()) != null) assign the next line each time through loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace the parameters in a loop because OleDBCommand does not support named parameters. The parameter replacement is made in the order you add Parameters, therefore you have to create a new command every run, because the 2nd loop run you add a 3rd and 4th parameter (while you only use two).

Comment: about the named parameters, they work fine for the first line, so I guess they should work everywhere.

Comment: i guess it doesn't matter how you name them at all. I updated my answer.